# java.lang.NumberFormatException for converting string to long

Tags: java, string, numberformatexception

I am trying to convert a string to long and it throws the `NumberFormatException`. I don't think it is beyond range of `long` at all.

Here is the code to convert, where `count_strng` is the String I want to convert to long. `trim()` function is not making any difference.

```
long sum_link = Long.parseLong(count_strng.trim());
```

Here is the stacktrace.

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0.003846153846153846"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:441)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:483)
```

Anyone knows what is the exact issue here?

Comment: Can you share the code you wrote that triggers this exception?

Comment: at least write some code. it is difficult to come up with an answer just by seeing the error :)

Comment: `0.003846153846153846` is not a long. Try Double.parseDouble

Comment: When you are a beginner, and learning something ... sorry to say: try to not "think". What you mean by think is that you have some "concept" in your head, and you want to apply it to the code in front of you. Bad idea. Because - when you dont know the things you are thinking about ... your "concept" is likely to be "wrong". Instead careful learn the "concept" first; then transform it into source code.
Long story short: it is not that the string is to long; it is simply that long numbers are **whole** numbers. 0 dot something is not ...

Comment: @Jägermeister Try not to think?  Like you say, he has such a concept.  And its wrong.  Whats wrong with him posting here so that someone can point out whats wrong?

Comment: What I mean is: he has a concept of "numbers" in his head - which doesn't match at all what the Java language things about numbers. So - forget about the half-baked thing in your head. Turn to the book, read the spec. I was merely poking on his statement "I don't think it is out of range". Although, reality was telling him through an exception message that something is wrong. So, the thing to learn here is: do not question reality. Instead, figure why the reality is like it is. And if there is a  misconception in your brain causing the disjoint.

Comment: Thank you very much ...using parseDouble worked for me. I got it clear. Sorry not to post the code in first attempt. I am trying to learn posting questions as well. Thank You all. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Long.parseLong()` is trying to parse the input string into a `long`. In Java, a `long` is [defined such that](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> The long data type is a 64-bit two's complement integer.

An integer is [defined such that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer):

> An integer (from the Latin integer meaning "whole") is a number that can be written without a fractional component.

The error you are getting shows the input string you are trying to parse is `"0.003846153846153846"`, which clearly **does have** a fractional component.

You should use `Double.parseDouble()` if you want to parse a floating point number.

Answer (score 9):

As your input string is actually not a **`long`**, parsing into **`long`** would throw **`NumberFormatException`**. Rather try this

```
Double d = Double.parseDouble(count_strng.trim());
Long l = d.longValue();
```

Comment: Minor point, but d.longValue() does not round - it just chops off the decimal portion like a cast would.

Answer (score 0):

Long types represents mathematical integers. (Integer also represents mathematical integers, but with a smaller range than Long)

Long and Integer cannot represent values that have a decimal point or a fractional component.  The parser enforces this rule by rejecting the string you gave it.

If you want to parse a string that may contain a decimal point and use the resulting value as a Long, you would first have to parse it as a Double and then convert it to a Long.

Conversion from Double to Long can be done one of two ways: Truncating the fractional part (basically just ignoring it) and rounding the fractional part mathematically.  To truncate, use a cast, to round use the `Math.round()` method.

Hers'a an example:

```
String s = "0.51"; // Greater than 0.50 so will round up
double d = Double.parseDouble(s);

System.out.println(d); // The parsed double

System.out.println((int)d); // Double converted to int and truncated (fractional part dropped)

System.out.println(Math.round(d)); // Double converted to int with mathematical rounding
```

This code will print

```
0.51
0
1
```

Also: `trim()`is a String function that removes whitespace characters from the string - it does not do any math.