# How to close a scanner object when input is taken in a loop?

Tags: java, exception

I am taking input from console  using while loop and calling my input() method.
But when i try to close a scanner object the it give run time error.
When object is not closed program runs correctly but warning is given by eclipse that **Resource leak: 's' is never closed**.
How to fix it ?
My code for taking input is

```
    String input()
    {
        try
        {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            String str=s.nextLine();
            s.close(); // error because of this 
            return str; 
        }

public class validation  {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    try
        {
            String name;
            String email_id;
            String number;
            validation v= new validation();
            do{
            System.out.println("Enter the name");
            name=v.input();
            }
            while (!(v.validate_name(name)) );

            do{
                System.out.println("Enter valid Mobile Number");
                number=v.input();
            }
            while(!(v.validate_number(Long.parseLong(number))) || !(v.filevalidate(number)));

            do{
            System.out.println("Enter valid Email_id");
            email_id=v.input();
            }
            while(!(v.validate_email(email_id)) || !(v.filevalidate(email_id)));

            v.writeToFile(name,number,email_id);
        }       
        catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
```

Output with error is

> Enter the name
>   Justin
>   Enter valid Mobile Number
>   java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

Comment: If you can add, how you are using this method in loop

Comment: you mention java.lang.NumberFormatException but this code is never through java.lang.NumberFormatException. The error is repleted  to another code

Comment: i have provided rest of the code

Comment: you should create 'Scanner' as privet field of 'validation' and initialize in construction and close it in end of the program then the issue can solve

Comment: although closing the scanner object won't give numberformatexception, you can handle same with :

Scanner scanner = null;
try {
    scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    //rest of the code
}
finally {
    if(scanner!=null)
        scanner.close();
}

Comment: Don't close the Scanner object. It needs to remain open for the duration of your program. If you close it, you also automatically close System.in. Just create a single Scanner object at the start of your program. Optionally close it only at the end of your entire program.

Comment: @PrakhaRaM it's not working.. same error is given

Comment: you are providing long format value only in mobile number? is space also there when you enter nunber

Comment: i have to convert String into long before validating a  number

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33176416/java-lang-numberformatexception-for-converting-string-to-long

Comment: v.validate_number(Long.parseLong(number) line is through number format exception please change 'validate_number' method to accept string parameter

Comment: the problem only occurs whenever i try to close my scanner class object .. otherwise my code is running fine

Comment: NumberFormatException is because scanner is not taking a input and it return null string which cannot be type cast to long .. My question is how to close my scanner object.

Comment: @Namanjain see my comment to K.venkatesh's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing a Scanner object causes it to also close its associated InputStream or file. If you were to use a `Scanner` in your `input()` method to read data from a file instead of from the keyboard, you might use it like this:

```
String input() {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(INPUT_FILE_NAME);
    Scanner s = new Scanner(is);
    String str = s.nextLine();
    s.close();
    return str;
}
```

As you see, the Scanner is closed, so that there are no resource leaks. If you didn't close it, the InputStream, which was opened on a file, would remain open. Just closing the Scanner also closes the InputStream on which the Scanner was constructed. So there is no need to close the InputStream too.

The above is equivalent to the following, but the code below is safer as it deals properly with exceptions:

```
String input() {
    try (
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(INPUT_FILE_NAME);
        Scanner s = new Scanner(is)
    ) {
        String str = s.nextLine();
        return str;
    }
}
```

This is the try-with-resources statement, which you can read about on Oracle's website or a good textbook. It ensures that the InputStream and the Scanner are always closed before the method returns, no matter what happens.

So why shouldn't we do the same with a Scanner that is opened on `System.in`? That is because `System.in` is an InputStream that we want to keep open for the whole duration of the program. If we close the Scanner, that would also close `System.in` and we don't want that. But now that we don't close the Scanner, we don't want to create a new Scanner every time we enter the `input()` method. We just want to create a single Scanner that lasts the duration of our program. One way to do this is by having it as a field:

```
public class Validation {
    private static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    String input() {
        return in.nextLine();
    }

    ...
}
```

Now the Scanner is created as soon as the JVM loads your class, and remains usable until your program exits.

I am not sure if Eclipse will still complain about a resource leak if you construct your Scanner object as a static field (I don't use Eclipse). Perhaps you can let me know if it does or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
String input(){
    Scanner s = null;
    try {
        s = new Scanner(System.in);
        //your code
    }
    finally {
        if(s!=null)
            s.close();
    }
    }
```

try like this and comment your response! Hope it works fine.
    can i see your filevalidate and validate_number methods!

Comment: 1. please format the code properly. 2. using `try-with-resources` is much simpler

Comment: try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in))  is this what you are saying?  @Jaroslaw Pawlak

Comment: This will not work. Closing the Scanner will also close `System.in`. Therefore when you call `input()` the second time, this method will attempt to create another Scanner object on the already-closed `System.in`, and fail. As was mentioned before in the comments: create your Scanner object at the start of your application, and optionally close your Scanner at the very end, just before your application terminates. (You don't really have to close the Scanner object at all.)

Comment: Does it affect  my program or program security if i will not close the scanner object @DodgyCodeException

Comment: @Namanjain no, it's ok as long as you only create it once (at the beginning of your program). Don't create it inside the `input()` method. Create it as a field of your class.