# Problem with the .onBindViewHolder (Can't find a solution for my code)

Tags: java

I know a lot of the posts on this site deal with the .onBindViewHolder but I haven't found the solution to my problem.
The code below is used to display a user's post (text, photos ....) but for me it is not displayed and this error appears.

***Adapter Post***

```
`public class AdapterPosts extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterPosts.MyHolder> {

    Context context;
    List<ModelPost> postList;

    public AdapterPosts(Context context, List<ModelPost> postList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.postList = postList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_posts, viewGroup, false);
        return new MyHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder myHolder, int i) {

        String uid = postList.get(i).getUid();
        String uEmail = postList.get(i).getuEMail();
        String uName = postList.get(i).getuName();
        String uDp = postList.get(i).getuDp();
        String pId = postList.get(i).getpId();
        String pTitle = postList.get(i).getpTitle();
        String pDescription = postList.get(i).getpDescr();
        String pImage = postList.get(i).getpImage();
        String pTimeStamp = postList.get(i).getpTime();

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(pTimeStamp));
        String pTime = DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm aa", calendar).toString();

        myHolder.uNameTv.setText(uName);
        myHolder.pTimeTv.setText(pTime);
        myHolder.pTitleTv.setText(pTitle);
        myHolder.pDescriptionTv.setText(pDescription);

        try {
            Picasso.get().load(uDp).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_default_img).into(myHolder.uPictureIv);

        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }
        if (pImage.equals("noImage")) {

            myHolder.pImageIv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else {
            try {
                Picasso.get().load(pImage).into(myHolder.pImageIv);

            }
            catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }



        myHolder.moreBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "More", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        myHolder.likeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Like", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        myHolder.commentBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Commenter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        myHolder.moreBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Partager", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return postList.size();
    }

    class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView uPictureIv, pImageIv;
        TextView uNameTv, pTimeTv, pTitleTv, pDescriptionTv, pLikesTv;
        ImageButton moreBtn;
        Button likeBtn, commentBtn, shareBtn;

        public MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            uPictureIv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.uPictureIv);
            pImageIv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pImageIv);
            uNameTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.uNameTv);
            pTimeTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pTimeTv);
            pTitleTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pTitleTv);
            pDescriptionTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pDescriptionTv);
            pLikesTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pLikesTv);
            moreBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.moreBtn);
            likeBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.likeBtn);
            commentBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.commentBtn);
            shareBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.shareBtn);

        }
    }
}`
```

***Error***

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ascolta, PID: 2215
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:557)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:636)
        at com.example.ascolta.adapters.AdapterPosts.onBindViewHolder(AdapterPosts.java:57)
        at com.example.ascolta.adapters.AdapterPosts.onBindViewHolder(AdapterPosts.java:26)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22419)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6584)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22419)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6584)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22419)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6584)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22419)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6584)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22419)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6584)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:530)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22419)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6584)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22419)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6584)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22419)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6584)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:1041)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22419)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6584)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3378)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2842)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1888)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8511)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

Thank you for you precious help
Have a nice day

Comment: Note that **Java is NOT the same as JavaScript**! They're different. Very different. Just like cat is different to catfish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must need to check the below code

```
    String pTimeStamp = postList.get(i).getpTime();

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(pTimeStamp));
    String pTime = DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm aa", calendar).toString();
```

it seems like `pTimeStamp` is returning the null value and due to that you are getting the `NumberFormatException`

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33176660/3546909) link

Comment: I checked at the link you provided me and applied what I saw there but it still gives me the same error. Could you send me the changes I should make? thank you for your help

Comment: Can you add the null check before parsing the `pTimeStamp`
So basically
```try{
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(pTimeStamp));
    String pTime = DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm aa", calendar).toString();
}catche(Exception e){
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks you it's a good soluce ! But now this error become E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ascolta, PID: 26300
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.ascolta.adapters.AdapterPosts.onBindViewHolder(AdapterPosts.java:80)              Very sorry for my question.

Comment: Chnge `noImage.equals("pImage")`

Comment: Thanks but noImage is not a variable

Comment: No I am telling you that below line can be the cause on Null pointer exception,
```if (pImage.equals("noImage")) {
    myHolder.pImageIv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}```